# custom jquery css images not found with grails 2.2.0 and resource plugin

Tags: css, jquery-ui, grails-2.2

Trying to use a custom jquery ui theme in grails 2.2.0 using the resource plugin.  However I can't seem to get it configured so that the images referenced inside the custom.css file will render.  For example I continue to get 404 errors for urls that look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/static/css/themes/south-street/images/ui-icons_eeeeee_256x240.png
```

I have tried the modules overide and my latest attempt I have the following module defined:
specifically referencing the css file.

```
 dashboard {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
            // dependsOn 'jquery-ui'
        resource url:'js/fg.menu.js'
        resource url:'jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.js'

        resource url:'css/main.css'
        resource url:'css/fg.menu.css'
        resource url:'css/arfnavigation.css'
        resource url:'css/themes/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css'

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I got this working by creating an images module and explicitly describing each image in my app that is referenced by a CSS file, then including that dependency.  I would like to know if this is the standard solution or if I missed something in my other configuration that would have handled this automatically.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try this post [Grails: Images / CSS missing from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432521/grails-images-css-missing-from-time-to-time/15174643#15174643).

It's was a bug in resource plugin.

In your BuildConfig.groovy in plugins use this:

runtime ":resources:1.2.RC2"